# Deploying vsts build artifact to local IIS server

Tags: .net, iis, deployment, azure-devops, artifacts

I need to understand the way to deploy DOTNET build artifacts from VSTS onto local IIS server. It generates a text file along with others in the artifact which shows the way to deploy. Within that it asks for WEBDEPLOY to be installed to run the .cmd file. I am still confused as to why i cannot just go to IIS admin and just import the said drop artifact.

Can someone suggest please.

[image: error]

[image: artifacts]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read here for the [WebPackage deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/deploying-web-packages)

Basically, this deployment model is just zip all the published artifacts like dlls, which makes the deployment easier by executing a single command,

`<projectname>.deploy.cmd /Y`

If you want to deploy manually, you just need to unzip the folder and copy and paste the bin and its corresponding folders into the physical location of the IIS web application.(localhost)

For AzureDevOps release pipeline you can use a simple Cmd Task/Batch Task to execute the `<projectname>.deploy.cmd`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Is Web Deploy used in CI pipeline when i automate this task.

Comment: @Salman Just configuration is more enough for a webPackage, For Deployment you can use the WebPackage Deploy with any command prompt/powershell task